# DIY Pot Noodle safe ingredients

Tags: food-safety, noodles, ramen

I'm looking to make some of these DIY pot noodles or "pot ramen" or whatever folk might call them. I've got a load of ideas for what to put in them but no idea how safe it will be to eat given the minimal cooking that's available by just pouring boiled water. So, can anyone advise if any of the following ingredients pose any risk if they are simply soaked in water and not drained or heated in any sustained fashion?

- Vermicelli Noodles
- Water Chestnuts
- Bean Sprouts
- Miso Paste

The Vermicelli I can find here in the UK all suggests that it needs to be soaked and drained. Is it safe to eat them with the water they were soaked in? Are there other kinds of noodles that can be prepared using only boiling water (which would then become some sort of "miso soup" in the blend of things)?

Food safety is the ultimate factor for me, I'm emetophobic so anything which could cause food poisoning will make me paranoid as hell.

Comment: Likely of interest : http://www.seriouseats.com/2014/09/diy-instant-noodle-cups-food-lab.html

Comment: Is it rice vermicelli, or wheat?  For the rice version, you can just let it sit in the hot water.  I'm not sure what the cooking time is on the wheat version, but I'd think that'd be more of an issue unless it was a nest of fresh pasta (which is often coated in flour to prevent sticking ... which will thicken the sauce, but won't make you sick unless you have problems with wheat in the first place)

Comment: Hi, @Joe - I've read that post (plus probably 30 or 40 similar ones). One problem I have is diet requirements, I have an onion intolerance which means I can't use a lot of ingredients from the lists I've seen, hence looking further afield to try source more info. I don't know if it's rice or wheat... The stuff I've got my eyes on right now says "Made from mung bean starch and water". I don't have any issues with wheat but onion, celery, loosely cooked egg (egg noodles are hit and miss, depends on the brand most of the time), and a few other things have bad effects on me.

Comment: The "make your own" is the section that is important on that article. It discusses which noodles work best and stresses that it's important to opt for stuff that's safe to eat raw or is already fully cooked and simply being reheated.

Comment: Food safety is fine, but health/nutrition concerns like "should I eat this much starch" are also off-topic here.

Comment: Would bean sprouts in any form not make a very much non-shelf stable, and also not long-term fridge stable, mix? All the beans sprouts I know are perishable as all heck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those items need to be heated to be safe, even if you eat them daily. Vermicelli is just pasta, made from wheat four, rice flour or mung bean flour. It may not be *palatable* under-cooked, but it won't hurt you unless you are sensitive to that ingredient. And if you *are* sensitive, cooking it won't help anyway.